# Need help to replace one tag with another

Tags: windows, batch, text-editors, tags

Anyone can help me on EmEditor Macro?

```
id="131"
        restype="x-p"
        phase-name="pretrans"><source>Good morning</source><seg-source><mrk
            mtype="seg"
            mid="1">Good morning</mrk></seg-source><target><mrk
            mtype="seg"
            mid="1"
            MadCap:segmentStatus="Untranslated"
            MadCap:matchPercent="0" /></target></trans-unit>
```

Shall it become

```
id="131"
        restype="x-p"
        phase-name="pretrans"><source>Good morning</source><seg-source><mrk
            mtype="seg"
            mid="1">Good morning</mrk></seg-source><target><mrk
            mtype="seg"
            mid="1"
            MadCap:segmentStatus="Untranslated"
            MadCap:matchPercent="0" />Good morning</target>"> </trans-unit>
```

I have 5000 files and I need to run this macro in Batch, so If anyone can help me to make this?

I want code to loop process in Batch file, source text could be anything.

Comment: Do you have to transform `d="131"` in `id="131"` too?  Check if it is correct this part `>">` in the last line. I mean if it is needed the double quote `"`. If not try to [edit your post](http://superuser.com/posts/784271/edit).

Comment: If you want in linux is _"simple"_ : `sed -i -e 's/\/><\/target><\/trans-unit>/\/>Good morning<\/target>\"> <\/trans-unit>/g' nomefile.txt` and you will substitute this string `/></target></trans-unit>` with the new one `/>Good morning</target>"> </trans-unit>` inside the file namefile.txt.  __WARNING__ it will change all the first strings that it finds in the file with the new ones. So if you want to use it you need to be sure that there is only one time that string, else you need to use a longer string. Maybe you need to escape the strings in your program too. In case of need ask

Comment: thnx a lot for reply, I need this either in Em-editor or CMD. Also, source text could be anything not only "Good Morning", and that shall replace text in N number of files.

Comment: It doesn't change with language. You need to find unique way to select __only__ the lines you want to substitute. And you have to be sure you take only those lines. With 5000 files is a moment to do mess. BTW in Linux you can do `for filename in $(ls *) ; do  echo "$filename" ; done` with instead of `echo $filename` the command you want. You can do it in a windows batch script too, only with a different _grammar_. Read [e.g. here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe) to have `sed` under windows.

Comment: I am not at all a technical person, any idea to write VB Script macro to achieve the same, MadCap:matchPercent="0" /></target></trans-unit> shall be replaced with the source content MadCap:matchPercent="0" />*********</target></trans-unit>

Comment: I am fine with VB script or CMD code, VB Script is supported by EM-Editor.

Comment: Maybe there is another missprint in the last line of the 2 file.
`MadCap:matchPercent="0" />Good morning</target>"> </trans-unit>` there is `target>">` now it seems it have to be only `target>` without double quote `"`. If you want I can write you an answer linux like that you can try to use with Cygwin and similar or to translate in VB. Last time I used it was VB6 and Caesar still were throwing dice in Gallia! :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you work with a lot of files you may pay a lot of attention. In the number reside the chaos.

In this moment I cannot help you with *Visual Basic* or *EmEditor Macro* but I can give you an alternative.

You can either install some *linux like* environment as CygWin, UnxUtils..., see link and possibility on [Is there any sed like utility for cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe), or you can try to translate what it follows in Visual Basic.

Milestones:

- Individuate a unique key. In your case should be the line that contains `MadCap:matchPercent="0"`
- Check that with your selection you will not take other *not wished* lines.
  Under linux you can do:

  ```
  grep -e 'MadCap:matchPercent="0"' AllMyFiles           
      # It gives a lot of lines maybe more that the number of files
  grep -e 'MadCap:matchPercent="0"' AllMyFiles | sort -u 
      # sort -u unique ... if you are lucky it's only one.
  ```

  You can use a more restricted key as

  ```
  grep -e 'MadCap:matchPercent="0" /></target></trans-unit>' AllMyFiles
  ```
- Now you can start to work on a single file for example substituting in that line `MadCap:matchPercent="0" /></target></trans-unit>` with your string.
  I write a little script even because it's more easy to read. Let's we call it `Change_One.sh` and invoke it with `/bin/bash Change_One.sh Myfile.txt`. Try before on a copied file:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  C="Good morning"                    # This is what you want to add
  A='MadCap:matchPercent="0" \/><\/target><\/trans-unit>'
  B='MadCap:matchPercent="0" \/>'${C}'<\/target>\"> <\/trans-unit>'
  sed  -i -e "s/${A}/${B}/g" $1       # Here you do it
  ```
- When it is all ok you can proceed and iterate on all the files

  ```
  #!/bin/bash 
  searchFiles='*.txt'                 # Here the 5000 files  
  C="Good morning"                    # This is what you want to add
                                      # $AA the not escaped string
                                      # $A and $B the escaped strings

  AA='MadCap:matchPercent="0" /></target></trans-unit>'
  A='MadCap:matchPercent="0" \/><\/target><\/trans-unit>'
  B='MadCap:matchPercent="0" \/>'${C}'<\/target>\"> <\/trans-unit>'

  for i in `grep -l -E "$AA"  $searchFiles`; do
    # echo "# Working on file " $i    # uncomment this line to test iterations
    sed -i -e "s/${A}/${B}/g" "$i"    # comment this line to test iterations
  done
  ```

  Note: with `grep` you can search the string inside the files, with `-l` you print only the filename, with  `command` you execute the command inside the script, and its output (the matching filenames) is used by the `for ... do done` cycle.